# Windows 10 firewall blocking all LAN traffic

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall, lan, windows-firewall

I don't know when or how this happened, but the first time I noticed there was a problem was when I could no longer check my modem status page at `http://192.168.100.1` - it immediately returns a `your Internet access is blocked` error. (I can check that page on any other device in my LAN, just not my main PC.)

Fast forward a month now, and I have come up against another problem - I cannot SSH into my VM (a VM which is running locally in VirtualBox).

I am at the point where the only thing I can think of to fix this is to reinstall Windows 10 once again.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: If you disable firewall completely, would it help?

Comment: Like @Alex said, does the modem status page and the SSH connection work if you disable the firewall? Have you checked your firewall settings? Is any other (non-local) traffic affected, or only LAN traffic?

Comment: I have tried resetting Windows Firewall to defaults and disabling it. Still no good. From what I can tell there is no problem with non-local traffic.

Comment: Can we ping 192.168.100.1 and the IP address of VM?  If so, can we telnet 80 and telnet 22?

Comment: Ping general failure

Comment: I uninstalled the NordVPN client and now it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the NordVPN client. Uninstalled it and now local traffic works again

Odd because it was only local network traffic that wasn't working

Comment: To add to the NordVPN answer, it's a setting called invisibility on LAN that was blocking your LAN traffic